# matrix problem solving - find the first column that has a value 1 in a matrix of 1's and 0's

Tags: algorithm, matrix

Was asked this question in a coding round:

Given a matrix of 0's and 1's where, in any row - the values will be ascending order. i.e 1's are always after the 0's. Consider the example :

```
0,0,0,1,1
0,0,1,1,1
0,0,0,0,1
1,1,1,1,1
0,0,0,0,0
```

Find the first column that has a 1. ( *from left - right* )

In this case the first column ( *in row 4* ) has a 1. 
**Answer is 1**

I suggested a column wise traversal across all rows and exit when the current column encounters 1 in any of the rows.

Since the worse case performance is n * n ( comparing every element in the matrix) the interviewer wasn't pleased and was looking for a efficient solution - what is an efficient solution here ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take advantage of the fact that the rows are sorted which is evident from *"in any row - the values will be ascending order. i.e 1's are always after the 0's"*

Let there be `m` rows and `n` columns. Do a binary search on first row to figure out the first `1` and store that index in some variable, say `index` (One may think of a better variable name. I am just focused here on solving the problem optimally.) Continue binary search on every row, update the `index` if the first column containing `1` has lesser index than the `index`. After doing binary search on every row, you'll end up with the result in `index` variable.

Time complexity: `m` rows * log2(`n` columns) i.e. `O(m * log2(n))`.

This is the approach I could think of, which is better than the brute force approach having `O(mn)` time complexity. I don't think there would be a more optimal approach in terms of time and space complexity, as one has to search for the first `1` in every row.

[I don't think I should add the details on how to do a binary search to figure out the first column containing a `1`. In case someone isn't very familiar with binary search, I leave this trivial part as an exercise.]

Comment: ahhh ! yeah that does it make better, knew I was missing something to do with the sorted input - binary search ! quite basic - such a shame it never occurred. Thanks for the answer  @Shridhar R Kulkarni